# How to selectively return rows inside a stored procedure on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a base stored procedure simply returning a select from the database, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM MyTable
END
GO
```

But now I need to execute some logic for every row of my select. According to the result I need to return or not this row. I would have my select statement running with a cursor, checking the rule and return or not the row. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE CURSOR_MYCURSOR FOR SELECT Id, Name FROM MyTable
  OPEN CURSOR_MYCURSOR
  FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_MYCURSOR INTO @OUTPUT1, @OUTPUT2

  WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
  BEGIN

  IF (SOME_CHECK)
    SELECT @OUTPUT1, @OUTPUT2
  ELSE
    --WILL RETURN SOMETHING ELSE

  END

END
GO
```

The first problem is that everytime I do `SELECT @OUTPUT1, @OUTPUT2` the rows are sent back as different result sets and not in a single table as I would need.

Sure, applying some logic to a row sounds like a "FUNCTION" job. But I can't use the result of the function to filter the results being selected. That is because when my check returns false I need to select something else to replace the faulty row. So, I need to return the faulty rows so I can be aware of them and replace by some other row.

The other problem with this method is that I would need to declare quite a few variables so that I can output them through the cursor iteration. And those variables would need to follow the data types for the original table attributes and somehow not getting out of sync if something changes on the original tables.

So, what is the best approach to return a single result set based on a criteria?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cursors are inherently slow.  I usually stay away from them.  Is the result sets the same for the different cases?  If so, just union a bunch of queries with different selects.  It will probably perform better than a cursor!

Comment: The problem with a function is that when it returns "false" i need to replace the data that would be returned with something else. So, I still would need to have a different select based on the function results which would leave me with the different result sets problem. I guess I can use the function along with the table variable. I'll post back here after testing. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look into a case statement?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx  On a searched case statement, you can use sub-queries to test the condition and return the correct field.  Stay away from functions.  They are also slow unless that are Table Value Functions.  Those could be used in this case.  Without business logic, I am just giving you ideas!

Comment: I'll check that. I noticed I can also add a join to my original select so that it already returns the replacement data. Then indeed case, function or udf would work to choose the right attributes. In my case, however, one row can be replaced by multiple ones. So, maybe I'll be slowing down my select too much. A lot to test from here on now. Which is great! =) Thanks for the input!! Really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use of cursors but easy solution to your question would be to use `table variable` or `temp table`

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
    (
     ColumnOne VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColumnTwo VARCHAR(20)
    )

CREATE TABLE #MyTable
    (
     ColumnOne VARCHAR(20)
    ,ColumnTwo VARCHAR(20)
    )
```

---

than inside your cursors you can insert records that match your logic

```
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (@Output1, @Output2)
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (@Output1, @Output2)
```

---

after you done with cursor just `select` everything from table

```
SELECT * FROM @MyTable
SELECT * FROM #MyTable
```

Comment: In my case they really are the same result sets as they originate from the select statement. I'll test the table variable. Thanks you two for helping.