# Selecting paged joined rows to a reliable limit of distinct related rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct, sql-server-2017

Consider a SQL Server 2017 database with four tables; **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**.

Table **D** references **C** with a foreign key constraint, as does **C** to **B**, and **B** to **A**.

The intent is to `INNER JOIN` each table together, selecting all rows in **D** which satisfy certain criteria, but only up to the point at which a defined number *n* of rows in table **A** have been joined to.

This should be page-able so a subsequent query can (with a defined offset) have its result set of **D** rows join indirectly to the next set of *n* table **A** rows.

Note that it is common for not all (or even most) of table **A**'s rows to not have one more valid relationship to a row in table **D**. Therefore using a basic `SELECT DISTINCT TOP n` would not provide a result set of table **D** rows with a reliable number of distinct table **A** relationships.

Comment: If you want to do paging, why aren't you using `fetch`/`offset`?

Comment: I am happy to use fetch / offset, but the "challenge" I have at the moment is to return a result set of D rows up to the defined limit of A rows. Paging is just a requirement of that solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I get this... You want only _n_ **distinct** (by PK is guess?) rows from `D` but it is no problem if the overall count of rows of the result is > _n_?

Comment: can you put table A in a subquery,thereby allowing for n rows?

Comment: I think I can simplify the problem by saying I want to join B to A, select rows from B, but limit the results back by a number which represents how many distinct rows in A have been joined to. Once I have joined 1 or more rows in B to (for example) 10 rows in A, I want to cease selecting rows from B and return what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Window Function for this

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
    *, dense_rank() over (order by A.ID) AS R
FROM
    A
    INNER JOIN B ON B.ID_A=A.ID
    INNER JOIN C ON C.ID_B=B.ID
    INNER JOIN D ON D.ID_C=C.ID
) AS RES
WHERE
RES.R<=PUT_LIMIT_OF_A_HERE
PUT_LIMITS_OF_ROWS_HERE
```

Comment: This looks very close to what I want, but I'm concerned the nesting means all results need to be retrieved before they are limited?

Comment: @Creyke to achive this you must use cursor + temp table. You stop after R have value you want. I see no way to improve this from pure SQL. Put above select as cursor select and do same as is here (look at the question and the answer altogether) https://stackoverflow.com/q/22669744/3114457